# Backbone merge on some attribute, save on id

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For an application i need to fetch default values, after which i merge in user specific values. These models are matched by a `key` attribute.

The defaults have no `id` the user specifics do have an `id`.

If i set my `idAttribute` to `key` it neatly merges the user specific values into the default models. But when i want to `save` this model, it will create the PUT url with the `key` attribute, because of the `idAttribute`. I want to save to collection.url + id, just as basic Backbone functionality.

Why not override the url? If a user edits to default model, it needs to POST to my REST server, normally a backbone model without an `id` will do this automatically. By overriding the URL, this doesn't work anymore.

changing the `idAttribute` before calling `.save()` doesn't seem to effect it.

Code example:

```
DefaultWeatherLimits = BackboneCollection.extend({
    url: 'limits/default',
    comparator: 'displayOrder',
    model: WeatherLimit,

    initialize: function () {

        this.fetch();

    }
});
```

Respond is an array like this (with more info in actual situation):

```
"[{"key":"MinHurricaneDistance","visualizationHint":"Value","value":300},{"key":"MaxHeadWavesHeight","visualizationHint":"Value","value":300}]"
```

The model looks like this:

```
WeatherLimit = Backbone.Model.extend({

    idAttribute : 'key'

});
```

Now , as test add in a User Specific model:

```
var fake = this.add({id: 99, key: "MinHurricaneDistance", checked: true}, {merge: true});
```

I want this `fake` model to save to 'limit/default/99', but it will save to 'limit/default/MinHurricaneDistance'
And i want the `MaxHeadWavesHeight` model to POST to '/limit/default', it will get an id in return and after i can save it to that id.

Comment: Can you provide code examples?

Comment: i've added code examples, hope it helps